# SQL IN or NOT IN depending on boolean parameter

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have a java boolean parameter that should tell if I check for values IN (x,y,z) or NOT IN (x,y,z) (based on true/false). How would I insert that 'NOT' into the SQL query? Should I use a simple String.replaceAll() or write a different query? Which is optimal?

Comment: Any chance there are null values in the IN list?

Comment: Write a different query. Otherwise you will end up writing a ["catch all query"](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: Yes, how would I check for empty IN()? Probably ignore WHERE if that IN() would be the only condition?

Comment: `WHERE col IN()` would be invalid SQL and a different problem. For the "catch all" route you could simple add `-1` to that list so that it is never empty and -1 wuld match no records... but I discourage it. Use distinct queries if you want _optimal_.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to write a single query that takes a parameter.  You can express the condition as:

```
select t.*
from t
where (@flag = 1 and x in (1, 2, 3)) or
      (@flag = 0 and x not in (1, 2, 3));
```

For performance, I think `union all` is better:

```
select t.*
from t
where @flag = 1 and x in (1, 2, 3)
union all
select t.*
from t
where @flag = 0 and x not in (1, 2, 3);
```

Of course, in java, you can just use two queries:

```
if flag then sql = . . . 
else sql = . . . ;
```

Then execute the sql in one step.

Comment: If using the former, you'd probably want to include the `RECOMPILE` option, as the query plan for the 2 queries could be quite different. If that isn't an option (due to using an older version of SQL Server) then you'd probably want to use dynamic SQL. I agree, however, handling which query to run in java is probably the far better option.